# R biglm predict searching for dependent variable

Tags: r

I'm using the biglm package to run a regression on a data set.  The regression runs fine using the following code:

```
chunkStart <- seq(1,150000000,1000000)
chunkEnd <- seq(1000000,151000000,1000000)
ff <- price ~ factor(Var1) + factor(Var2)

#for(i in 1:length(chunkStart)){
for(i in 1:5){

startRow <- chunkStart[i]
endRow <- chunkEnd[i]    
curchunk <- data.frame( price=x[startRow:endRow,1]
     ,Var1=factor( x[startRow:endRow,6], levels=1:3), Var2= factor( x[startRow:endRow,7], levels=1:3 ) )

    if(i == 1){
    a <- biglm(ff,curchunk )
    }
    if(i != 1){
    a <- update(a,curchunk )
    }
rm(curchunk )
gc()
print(paste(i, " | ",startRow ," | ",endRow ," | ", sep=""))
flush.console()
}

> summary(a)
Large data regression model: biglm(ff, curchunk)
Sample size =  5000000 
                 Coef    (95%     CI)    SE p
(Intercept)    0.0457  0.0454  0.0461 2e-04 0
factor(Var1)2  0.0189  0.0184  0.0194 2e-04 0
factor(Var1)3  0.0148  0.0142  0.0155 3e-04 0
factor(Var2)2 -0.0331 -0.0335 -0.0326 2e-04 0
factor(Var2)3 -0.0417 -0.0426 -0.0408 4e-04 0
```

The problems come when I try to predict using the biglm object, 'a'.

```
> df1 <- data.frame(y[1:1000,])
> pred1 <- predict(a, df1)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'price' not found
```

Why is the `predict` function looking for the `price`/ dependent variable?  Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
> head(df1)
  Var1 Var2
1    3    3
2    3    1
3    3    2
4    2    1
5    2    2
6    1    1
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 3 3 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ Var2: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
> pred1 <- predict(a, df1)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'price' not found
```

Comment: What is y?  I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: @Dason: ff <- price ~ factor(Var1) + factor(Var2)

Comment: I mean when you define df1 you have "y" but what is y?

Comment: @Dason: Sorry, you're right, 'y' is a big.matrix object with the test data I'm using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it is looking for the dependent variable is that the predict method uses a call to `model.frame` from the stats package, and that function requires all the variables to be present in the new data. This is indicated on the `model.frame` help page without explanation for the motivation behind it.

All you actually need to do about this is create a variable in your new data that has the same name as the dependent variable, then fill it with zeroes (or any non-missing value). So it should work if you run this:

```
df1$price <- 0
pred1 <- predict(a, df1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is what I am looking for.